# SQL prepare for WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, sql, security, go, prepared-statement

While we write a web application, we will use SQL prepare instead of concat SQL strings to avoid SQL injection. For example:

```
sql.exec("select * from user where user_id=?", user_id)
```

But how to write prepare `WHERE...IN` in SQL? For example:

```
sql.exec("select * from user where user_id in ?", user_ids)
```

If it is impossible. What is the proper way to avoid SQL injection in such a situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear. I'm not asking the way in PHP. I'd like to know if there are some general ways in the language who supports the MySQL driver.

Comment: What is the application host language?  Note that most drivers don't support array parameters, so the essential answer is the same - construct a list of replacement variables, then bind the values.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse  I'm using Golang for now.

Comment: How about: `sql.exec("select * from user where user_id in (?)", "1,2,3,4")`?

Answer (score 0):

change user_ids string to id array:

```
idArr = strings.Split(user_ids, ",")
```

create sql:

```
vals := []interface{}{}
sqlStr := "select * from user where user_id in ("
for _,v := range idArr {
    vals = append(vals, v)
    sqlStr += "?,"
}
sqlStr = strings.TrimRight(sqlStr, ",")
sqlStr += ")"

stmt, err := db.Prepare(sqlStr)
if err!=nil{
    return err
}
defer stmt.Close()

rows, err := stmt.Query(vals...)
```